# Can i make py2exe executable who take flag or variable in cmd console

Tags: python, cmd

i would like to know if there is a way to make a python script that after being transform into an exe whith py2exe would be usable whith flags or input variables in the cmd Console from windows
I explain myself, some .exe are used in cmd windows shell whith flags or variables like this:

```
myexe -v flagValue variable
```

So my question is which module should i use or how should look my python script to took things like that when generated whith py2exe?
Maybe there is option to add in py2exeSetup.py too?

And if anyone have Clue on how to get the return of such a script too, i will gladly take it too :D

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to with py2exe, but rather a question about argparse module.

Comment: Great i think this answer my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you want your program to do, it can do after being turned into a windows executable.  To read command-line arguments, use the `argparse` stdlib module, or if you have to run with Pythons < 2.7, `optparse`.